# Mysql/VB.Net load map markers not in certain range from eachoter

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net, google-maps, maps

I have a database with a huge amount of cities in the world. Each one has a coordinate (lat,lng) and a populairity index.

Now I want to show them on a map, but I dont want to create clusters.

For example, if I have a spot on a map where there are 5 cities within 50 km of eachother, I only want to show the one that has the highest populairity. When the user zooms in, I want show up the other ones.

The desired result is like the cities on Google Maps. When you zoom out, you only see some important cities, when you zoom in, other ones show up.

How can I accomplish this?

[image]

code so far:

**Mysql:**

```
SELECT * FROM cities 
WHERE lat > '[Boundingbox min latitude]'
AND  lat < '[Boundingbox max latitude]'
AND lng > '[Boundingbox min longitude]'
AND lng < '[Boundingbox max longitude]'
ORDER BY populairity DESC LIMIT 100;
```

And the results is add in the map. I think I need to loop through the cities in .NET and match avery city to each other one. But that will be a hell of a loop.

Comment: Show the code you have so far

Comment: One strategy would be to first decide the minimum distance there should be between named places for the current level of zoom. Then create a list of places that are in the current map window, sorted by popularity. Set the label for the most popular place, then check if the next most popular place is at least the minimum distance from the labels you have already set and if it is, set it. Continue through the list of places.

Comment: That sounds like a decent strategy.

Comment: @Blackwood you should write it as an answer couse your method works very well..

Comment: Look into the spatial extensions for MySQL if performance is an issue. Doesn't Google Maps already show cities? How are you present the map to the user?

Comment: Maps does show places. But I need only a small selection.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a possible strategy

1. Decide the minimum distance there should be between named places for the current level of zoom.
2. Then create a list of places that are in the current map window, sorted by popularity.
3. Create the label for the most popular place.
4. Check if the next most popular place is at least the minimum distance from all the labels you have already created and if so create it.
5. Continue through the list of places.

The more labels you create, the less chance there is that the next most popular place will be at least the minimum distance from all the other labels. To save time, you might want to set an arbitrary limit on the number of labels you will create (perhaps based on the size of the map window), and stop processing the list of places once you have created that many labels.